# Sequelize fazendo select incorreto

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, sequelize-js

Tenho uma api em nodeJs

**www:**

```
...
db.sequelize.transaction() 
    .then(() => { 
        server.listen(port); 
        server.on('error', onError); 
        server.on('listening', onListening);
})
...
```

**models:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const RCC = sequelize.define('RCC', {
    RCC_RESP: DataTypes.STRING,
    RCC_CCT: DataTypes.STRING,   
    R_E_C_N_O_:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    D_E_L_E_T_: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(1),
      allowNull: false, //se aceita nulo
      autoIncrement: false
    }
  }, {});
  RCC.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return RCC;
};
```

**controller:**

```
class RCC {
    async show(db) {
        return await db.RCC.findAll({
            where: {
                RCC_CCT: '050101'
            }
        })
    }
}

export default new RCC();
```

**Routes:**

```
...
   routes.get('/showAll', async (req, res) => {
        const show = await RESP.show(db);
        if (show) {
            res.status(200).send(show)
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ message: 'No Data Found' });
        }
    })
```

o nome da tabela (nao criei pela api) no meu bd é: **RCC**, só que quando vou dar um console pra ver como ta indo a requisição, ele da um select na tabela (nao existe) RCCs, isso ta sendo padrão.

***Tem alguma forma de mudar isso? no lugar de fazer um select na tabela RCCs, fazer realmente na tabela RCC?***

Answer (score 1):

Que bom que resolveu, entretanto, notei algo diferente na forma de utilização do Model do Sequelize.

Geralmente, você necessita apenas importar o model e utilizar ele para realizar as queries, exemplo:

```
const RCCModel = require(path/to/models);
class RCC {
    async show(db) {
        return await RCCModel.findAll({
            where: {
                RCC_CCT: '050101'
            }
        })
    }
}

export default new RCC();
```

Isto porque na pasta models, há um arquivo com o seguinte código:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const config = require('../../config/database')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
)

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    )
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file))
    db[model.name] = model
  })

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Especialmente nesse arquivo, é injetado o db (igual ao seu) nos models que estão na pasta Models.

Essa configuração é criada automaticamente com o comando `$ sequelize init`, através do [sequeli-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli)

Comment: mas é exatamente isso que eu faço

Answer (score 0):

a documentação da qual eu consegui resolver:
https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#configuration

Coloquei no meu model:

```
freezeTableName: true
```

e foi resolvido